# rgrass7: Invalid number of 'breaks' for hist.default

Tags: r, grass-7.0

So I just started to use the library `rgrass7` from R and I got this error

> Error in hist.default(v, main = main, plot = plot, ...) : 
>     invalid number of 'breaks'

Or, using the summary function, I get errors like:

> NA's         1      1      1      1

So I was wondering what was wrong.Because I don't know if it's the function at this point or it's my GRASS session that is open, or anything at all.

The code that I used is pretty straightforward:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rgrass7)
initGRASS(gisBase = "C:/GRASS/GRASS_GIS_7_3_svn", home = tempdir(), 
      gisDbase = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/data",
      location = "Thesis", mapset = "user" override=T)

 my_vmaps=execGRASS("g.list", parameters = list(type = "vector", pattern = "precip*"))

 r1=readRAST(c("gera.1","gera.2","gera.3","gera.4"))
 r=brick(r1)
 hist(r$gera.1)
 summary(r)
 hist(r1 )
```

Comment: Are you looking for `hist(r)` and not `r1`?

Comment: I just want to print a histogram for now of my rasters, because I realize `readRast` fetches a spatialGrid but the values of that variable (which is r1) are null,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, so the problem was that I had to set a region, either from R or from within GRASS. See the code below:

```
initGRASS(gisBase = "C:/GRASS/GRASS_GIS_7_3_svn", 
      home=tempdir(),gisDbase = "C:/Users/anna/Desktop/data",
      location = "Thesis",mapset = "user", override=T)
      region=execGRASS("g.region",raster="gera.1")
      r=readRAST("raster.1")
```

Now if one does not set the region, the result would be a matrix with NA values, that is because when you are using the execGRASS function, you are basically using the syntax and the functionality of GRASS which uses a region to execute diffrent functions, if you haven't set a region, or your data are off that boundary zone, you will probably have NA values where you should have actual values. That is something where you can find from the GRASS manual [here](https://grassbook.org/) or from [here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads147/ebook/636694/Springer%20(2004)%20E-Book%20-%20Open%20Source%20Gis%20A%20Grass%20Gis%20Approach.pdf).

Comment: Did you change your code accordingly ?

Comment: @gisnside Well, yeah, see my edit

Comment: Thanks ! It will be useful for people having the same problem :)